# Sum together list of F expressions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-aggregation

Is there a way to specify (in an annotation or aggregation) that a sequence of `F` expressions should be summed together without manually typing out `F("first_prop") + F("second_prop") + ...`?

I want something similar to how python's `sum()` function allows you to pass an iterable and get the sum of the values in the iterable i.e. `sum([1,2,3])` returns `6`.

Concretely, I want something that looks like this:

```py
class Tree(TimeStampedModel):
  leaf_count = models.IntegerField()
  branch_count = models.IntegerField()

Tree.objects.create(leaf_count=60, branch_count=8)
Tree.objects.create(leaf_count=30, branch_count=3)

# now I want to annotate a combined count using my imaginary IterableSum aggregator
combined_sums = list(
  Tree.objects.all().annotate(
    combined_count=IterableSum(fields=[F("leaf_count"), F("branch_count")])
  ).values_list("combined_count", flat=True)
)

combined_sums # [68, 33]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with `sum` is that it starts with `0` as initial value. You can you can use `reduce` from `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

from django.db.models import F

combined_sums = list(
    Tree.objects.values(
        combined_count=reduce(add, [F('leaf_count'), F('branch_count')]),
        flat=True,
    )
)
```

although strictly speaking, that is not even necessary, you can just use `sum`, since it will add up `0` with `F('leaf_count')`:

```
from django.db.models import F

combined_sums = list(
    Tree.objects.values(
        combined_count=sum([F('leaf_count'), F('branch_count')]),
        flat=True,
    )
)
```

Then this will have a `+ 0` in the query, which might not be ideal.

This is because `sum` does *not* sum only integers, indeed, you can for example sum `F` objects:

```
In [11]: sum([F('foo'), F('bar')])
Out[11]: <CombinedExpression: Value(0) + F(foo) + F(bar)>
```

Comment: `"Thank you!! " * 100` I had tried using reduce but with a custom function that did manual addition using `+`, and that didn't quite give the correct `CombinedExpression`. Your solution did! 